# Play a list of videos without flicker (seamless) in WinRT

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-runtime, mediaelement

I have a list of videos, and I need to create a playlist to play this list. I tried to do that by setting the `MediaElement` source to the next video in the `MediaEnded` event.

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(first, UriKind.Relative);
mediaElement.MediaEnded += (s, ea) =>
             { 
                    ea.Handled = true; 
                    mediaElement.Source = new Uri(second, UriKind.Relative);
             };
```

The problem the transition between the first to the second video takes 1 second. I want to play the whole list like one long video. Is that possible?

Comment: The MediaElements in WinRT do flicker a lot! I don't know the answer, but maybe MediaElement accepts some sort of a playlist file as input. Otherwise - you could dig into the Media Framework where you would have more control over this, although it would be quite a bit of work and involve some low level C++ code.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that, and the MediaElement does have some properties like RealTimePlayBack and AutoLoad, but they dont help at all..

Comment: Well, I am interested in what you find out then. Last time I checked - my videos were starting delayed, sometimes with a green rectangle before they started and I had to overlay an image of the first frame on top of the MediaElement until the video started. Also using multiple MediaElements was not allowed. Maybe something's changed, since that might have been in Consumer Preview.